# How to unstack pandas with columns that are both arrays and plain int?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

Given a `pandas dataframe` that looks like this:

```
col1      |  col2      |  col3
[0,0,0,0]   [0,0,0,0]    0.265
[0,0,0,0]   [0,0,0,0]    0.243
[0,0,0,0]   [0,0,0,0]    0.289
[0,0,0,0]   [0,0,0,0]    0.213
```

How can I unstack it so that it looks something like this?

```
    col_all
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.265]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.265]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.243]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.289]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.213]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to just sum (assuming `col1` and `col2` objects are `list`s)

```
df.col1 + df.col2 + df.col3.transform(lambda item: [item])

0    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.265]
1    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.243]
2    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.289]
3    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.213]
```

For arrays

```
df.agg(lambda s: np.concatenate(s, axis=None), 1)
```

Notice that these operations will not be fast. Maybe you should consider not using `pandas` if you intend to perform operations on columns that have `dtype` object. Consider using list of lists

Comment: col1 and col2 are actually not lists, but arrays

Comment: I like your second answer, but in my case it throws an error. Do you know what might be causing this? This is the error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7159, 121), indices imply (7159, 5)

Comment: @callmeGuy This error is not on the `agg` itself, but rather when you try to assign back to the `df` as a column, right? How are you assigning it?

Comment: I am assigning it as df[['col1','col2']].agg(lambda s: np.concatenate(s, axis=None), 1)

Answer (score 1):

```
Well there are actually multiple ways to do it. Unfortunately pandas does not have any function like this but you can use other
functions.In case of Python,
I'd prefer to use built-in functions in Reduce, as they would be faster as compared to using a lambda.'
using Reduce function.
import operator
import functools

list = [[1, 2], [2], [2, 3]]
ab=functools.reduce(operator.add, list)
print(ab);

**Output is** 
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Ikhtia how can i apply this on a pandas?